# Observer is not triggering when value is changed from onActivityResult()

Tags: android, observable, lifecycle, android-livedata

I have an **Activity A**. In this activity I have `MutableLiveData` ,`id`. When a button is clicked, I start an **Activity B** through `startActivityForResult()`. After doing some work, I finish **Activity B** & the `onActivityResult()` method is trigger. In this method, I change the value of `MutableLiveData()` ,`id`.

```
id.value = 5 // ex
```

But the following code is not triggering:

```
id.observe(this, Observer {
       // do-something if triggered
    })
```

I suspect there is a change of owner when the **Activity B** is started. What should I do to trigger the observable data from `onActivityResult()`?
Please help.

Comment: why not use 2 fragments and use shared view model scoped to lifecycle of activity that way you don't need 2 activities

Comment: You can check this answer for shared view model solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55060912/4699509

Comment: Can you check if the observable also works after unlock?

Comment: @Raghunandan That would be the best practice I assume. But is there any quick fix for this current scenario?

Comment: if you have the same instance of mutable live data and your are observing on the same you should be able to change the value. can you check that first. If not i suggest you use fragments

Comment: Yes, this is the same instance of mutable live data which is placed in Activity A's viewModel class.

Comment: there is a lib by some who has created sharedview models for activities with singleton view models and livedata. https://github.com/FarshadTahmasbi/Vita and i am not sure of the cons and pros of it. but this might help of a quick fix to share data between activities. But please look into the cons before using it in production

Comment: and do read up on https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/29

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Sir! The reason observer was not triggered because I finished the parent activity before the value changed.